# Motivation behind Definition of Projection [Poole P27]

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, visualization

In the long paragraph above equation $(2)$, http://mathinsight.org/dot_product avers:

> This leads to the definition that the dot product $\mathbf{a⋅b}$, divided by $∥\mathbf{b}∥$ (= magntitude of $\mathbb{b}$), is the projection of $\mathbf{a}$ onto $\mathbf{b}$: 
>   $\text{projection of $\mathbf{a}$ onto  } \mathbf{b} = \color{green}{\dfrac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}}{\|\mathbf{b}\|}} = \|\mathbf{a}\| \cos\theta.$

Yet P27 in David Poole avouches:

> If $\mathbf{a \neq 0,b} \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then 
>   $\text{projection of $\mathbf{a}$ onto  } \mathbf{b} = proj_b(\mathbf{a}) = \dfrac{\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}}\mathbf{b} = \color{green}{\dfrac{\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a}}{|\mathbf{b}|}}\dfrac{\mathbf{b}}{|\mathbf{b}|} .$

Would someone please reconcile these two definitions? Why is Poole's normalised (thanks to $\dfrac{\mathbf{b}}{|\mathbf{b}|}$)?
mathinsight.org contains pictures so I thought to include Poole's:

[image]

Comment: There is a certain degree of inconsistency in the use of the word "projection".  In the second definition you have quoted, the projection is a *vector*, namely the vector ${\bf p}$ in your diagram.  In the first it is a *scalar*, namely the length of this vector.  Both interpretations are found, and you need to carefully check each source you read to see which one they are using.

Comment: @David: a scalar it is, but only up to sign is it a length (when *θ* is beyond 90°, **a⋅b** is negative).